# Spring Batch 2 different jobs

Tags: spring, spring-batch

In my Spring Boot application I have defined a Spring Batch job

```
    @Bean
    public Job reportJob() {
        //@formatter:off
        return jobBuilderFactory
                .get(REPORT_JOB_NAME)
                    .flow(step1())
                        .on("*").to(step2())
                            .on("*").to(step3())
                    .end().build();
        //@formatter:on
    }
```

and use it in another class via bean injection:

```
@Autowired
private Job reportJob;
```

Right now I don't understand how to define 2 different jobs and inject them into the same class. How to distinguish between them?

Comment: use @Qualifier with a different name for second job

Comment: Thanks, now everything works fine